# Kubectl error upon applying agones fleet: ensure CRDs are installed first

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, agones

I am using minikube (docker driver) with kubectl to test an agones fleet deployment. Upon running `kubectl apply -f lobby-fleet.yml` (and when I try to apply any other agones yaml file)  I receive the following error:

```
error: resource mapping not found for name: "lobby" namespace: "" from "lobby-fleet.yml": no matches for kind "Fleet" in version "agones.dev/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
```

lobby-fleet.yml:

```
apiVersion: "agones.dev/v1"
kind: Fleet
metadata:
  name: lobby
spec:
  replicas: 2
  scheduling: Packed
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        mode: lobby
    spec:
      ports:
      - name: default
        portPolicy: Dynamic
        containerPort: 7600
        container: lobby
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: lobby
            image: gcr.io/agones-images/simple-game-server:0.12 # Modify to correct image
```

I am running this on WSL2, but receive the same error when using the windows installation of kubectl (through choco). I have minikube installed and running for ubuntu in WSL2 using docker.

I am still new to using k8s, so apologies if the answer to this question is clear, I just couldn't find it elsewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to create a resource of kind `Fleet`, you have to apply the Custom Resource Definition (CRD) that defines what is a `Fleet` first.

I've looked into the YAML installation instructions of agones, and the [manifest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googleforgames/agones/release-1.23.0/install/yaml/install.yaml) contains the CRDs. you can find it by searching `kind: CustomResourceDefinition`.

I recommend you to first try to install according to [the instructions in the docs](https://agones.dev/site/docs/installation/install-agones/yaml/#installing-agones).