# getting error while installing kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl apply -f

```
https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml
configmap/calico-config unchanged
service/calico-etcd unchanged
serviceaccount/calico-cni-plugin unchanged
serviceaccount/calico-kube-controllers unchanged
resource mapping not found for name: "calico-etcd" namespace: "kube-system" from "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
resource mapping not found for name: "calico-node" namespace: "kube-system" from "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
resource mapping not found for name: "calico-kube-controllers" namespace: "kube-system" from "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
resource mapping not found for name: "calico-cni-plugin" namespace: "" from "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
resource mapping not found for name: "calico-cni-plugin" namespace: "" from "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
resource mapping not found for name: "calico-kube-controllers" namespace: "" from "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
resource mapping not found for name: "calico-kube-controllers" namespace: "" from "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

ensure CRDs are installed first[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5zbw.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72243069/13133349 maybe this could help you

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're trying to install outdated manifests. The API versions of the resources you're applying have been deprecated in the k8s version you have. See the deprecation guide [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/).

You have to use the latest version which will have the `v1` version of these manifests.